# Unsubscribing from ROS Topic - Python

Tags: ros, python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a Class and in its init function, I subscribe to a camera, whose callback function is created in my class. i.e:

```
class example(object):
  def __init__(self):
    rospy.subscriber("/cameras/left_hand_camera/image",Image,self.callback_viewer)
  def callback_viewer(self,data):
    try:
      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)
    cv2.imshow("window", cv_image)
```

So for the purposes of my project, I need to create another class, which, in addition to doing some other stuff, unsubscribe to all the topics it is currently subscribing to. but I don't know how to use the unsubscriber function listed [here](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html)

Can anyone help me with that, how would i use that function?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239944/unsubscribing-from-ros-topic---python/) by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to use the `unregister` message on a subscriber object, you need a subscriber object. This subscriber object is returned by `rospy.subscriber`, so I'd recommend that you do:

```
class example(object):
  def __init__(self):
    # save the subscriber object to a class member
    self.sub = rospy.subscriber("/cameras/left_hand_camera/image",Image,self.callback_viewer)

  def callback_viewer(self,data):
    try:
      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)
    cv2.imshow("window", cv_image)

  def unsubscribe(self):
    # use the saved subscriber object to unregister the subscriber
    self.sub.unregister()
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-07-20**:
Ahh that makes perfect sense thank you so much!